# Memory used up for loading data alone in Keras program

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

My code is for training vgg16 from custom data. Two classes, Diseased and not diseased.
I have around 3400 Images, The problem is while loading the data-set to memory.The above-mentioned process utilizes 99% of ram memory and it gets stuck.I am using spyder,however when I followed another example which has lower data size it works fine. My question is as follows Can anyone suggest an efficent method to run it without loading all the images into the memory? Because this is eventually leading to the blue screen of death.
Ps:my system is capable of  running deeplearning codes.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import merge, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split



# Loading the training data
PATH = os.getcwd()
# Define data path
data_path = PATH + '/data'
data_dir_list = os.listdir(data_path)

img_data_list=[]

for dataset in data_dir_list:
    img_list=os.listdir(data_path+'/'+ dataset)
    print ('Loaded the images of dataset-'+'{}\n'.format(dataset))
    for img in img_list:
        img_path = data_path + '/'+ dataset + '/'+ img 
        img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
        x = image.img_to_array(img)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
        x = preprocess_input(x)
#       x = x/255
        print('Input image shape:', x.shape)
        img_data_list.append(x)

img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
#img_data = img_data.astype('float32')
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,1,0)
print (img_data.shape)
img_data=img_data[0]
print (img_data.shape)


# Define the number of classes
num_classes = 2
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')

labels[0:2345]=0
labels[2245:3567]=1


names = ['YES','NO']

# convert class labels to on-hot encoding
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)

#Shuffle the dataset
x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)
# Split the dataset
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

#########################################################################################
# Custom_vgg_model_1
#Training the classifier alone
image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

model = VGG16(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=True,weights='imagenet')
model.summary()
last_layer = model.get_layer('fc2').output
#x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(last_layer)
custom_vgg_model = Model(image_input, out)
custom_vgg_model.summary()

for layer in custom_vgg_model.layers[:-1]:
    layer.trainable = False

custom_vgg_model.layers[3].trainable

custom_vgg_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])


t=time.time()
#   t = now()
hist = custom_vgg_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=12, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
print('Training time: %s' % (t - time.time()))
(loss, accuracy) = custom_vgg_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))


####################################################################################################################

#Training the feature extraction also

image_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

model = VGG16(input_tensor=image_input, include_top=True,weights='imagenet')

model.summary()

last_layer = model.get_layer('block5_pool').output
x= Flatten(name='flatten')(last_layer)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)
custom_vgg_model2 = Model(image_input, out)
custom_vgg_model2.summary()

# freeze all the layers except the dense layers
for layer in custom_vgg_model2.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

custom_vgg_model2.summary()

custom_vgg_model2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adadelta',metrics=['accuracy'])

t=time.time()
#   t = now()
hist = custom_vgg_model2.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=12, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
print('Training time: %s' % (t - time.time()))
(loss, accuracy) = custom_vgg_model2.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=10, verbose=1)

print("[INFO] loss={:.4f}, accuracy: {:.4f}%".format(loss,accuracy * 100))

#%%
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# visualizing losses and accuracy
train_loss=hist.history['loss']
val_loss=hist.history['val_loss']
train_acc=hist.history['acc']
val_acc=hist.history['val_acc']
xc=range(12)

plt.figure(1,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_loss)
plt.plot(xc,val_loss)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.title('train_loss vs val_loss')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'])
#print plt.style.available # use bmh, classic,ggplot for big pictures
plt.style.use(['classic'])

plt.figure(2,figsize=(7,5))
plt.plot(xc,train_acc)
plt.plot(xc,val_acc)
plt.xlabel('num of Epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.title('train_acc vs val_acc')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(['train','val'],loc=4)
#print plt.style.available # use bmh, classic,ggplot for big pictures
plt.style.use(['classic'])
```

Comment: @ldavid here is the vgg code i told you about also could you look into the issue I posted along with the code

Comment: also, fine-tuning with above snippet for fine-tuning gets me an accuracy of only 50%

Comment: You can use fit_generator with Python generator that loads data batch by batch.